# Clearing the terminal leads to strange behavior

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am using VSCODE and the powershell terminal. Sometimes I want to clear my terminal due to a lot of errors and warnings, so I figured typing `clear` will do it but that doesn't clear the buffer.

So I found a solution which is to add the following to the `keybindings.json` file:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+k",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    }
]
```

Now while this works well, it generates weird behavior in my terminal. As shown in the picture that I have inserted, it allows me to type two characters on the first row but then it jumps down to the last row and let's me finish. How do I fix this?

[image: TERMINAL IMAGE]

Comment: Anyone who can help?

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell? This is not a PowerShell code issue/problem, which of course what this Q&A channel is here to help with.. It is a user-working environment-specific issue.  So, I'd suggest you post your query to say SuperUser or the [VSCode specific stackexchange Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code).

Comment: @postanote, it _is_ a PowerShell problem. It doesn't happen with other shells.

Comment: @postanote I should of been more clear about this in my post but this does only happen in PowerShell.

Comment: No worries. Stuff happens. Yet, as `mklement0`, it's a bug, so, the workaround provided is , what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a **bug in PowerShell** up to at least v7.3.3 (including Windows PowerShell) / v2.2.6 of the `PSReadLine` module, and it looks like there may be a bug in  *both*:

- Unloading `PSReadLine` (`Remove-Module PSReadLine`) (during troubleshooting; unloading this module is *not* a viable solution, because it severely degrades the command-line editing experience) only makes the problem go away on *Windows*:

  - Note: Unloading isn't effective in the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) provided via the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), because it seems to use a private copy that cannot be unloaded.
- On macOS (possibly also on Linux?), the problem occurs even with `PSReadLine` unloaded (also in a regular terminal / general-purpose shell, i.e. outside the PIC).

Specifically, when Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal is cleared (which includes the scrollback buffer) via a keyboard shortcut (rather than using a command submitted from inside the terminal), PowerShell / `PSReadLine` is unaware of that fact, and subsequent keyboard input appears on the *original* line, i.e. wherever the cursor happened to be *before* the screen was cleared.

Relevant **bug reports**:

- For `PSReadLine`: [GitHub issue #841](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/841)
- For PowerShell itself: [GitHub issue #19479](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19479)

---

**Workarounds**:

**Note**:

- The workarounds below **must be placed in your `keybindings.json` file, inside the top-level array (`[ … ]`)**; use `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` from the command palette to open this file for editing.
  If there are preexisting definitions and you want to place the objects below *after* them, be sure to place a `,` after the closing `}` of the last preexisting definition; to place them *before* the preexisting ones, be cause to append a `,` to the last closing `}` below.
- If you never work with `cmd.exe` as a shell, you can *omit* the first definition from each workaround and remove the  `&& terminalShellType == 'pwsh'` part from the `"when":` property of the second one. For most shells sending the extra <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> is a benign no-op in this context (it clears the screen too, but preserves the scrollback buffer), whereas `cmd.exe` doesn't understand this key chord and *prints* `^L` instead.

**Visual Studio Code v1.77+ workaround**:

Visual Studio Code v1.77+ now supports executing *multiple* commands in response to a single keyboard shortcut - see [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings?ref=matcha.fyi#_running-multiple-commands).

As you've discovered yourself, pressing <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> *in addition* to <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> makes PowerShell aware of the new cursor position, which fixes the problem.

Since <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> translates into control character FF (Form Feed), the latter can be sent as a key chord to the terminal, after having also run the `"workbench.action.terminal.clear"` command.

Therefore:

- **Caveat**: The definitions below use **`ctrl+shift+k` rather than `ctrl-k`**, because the latter appears not to work with `runCommands`, **due to an apparent bug** as of Visual Studio Code v1.77.3 - see [GitHub issue #179724](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179724).

```json
// General definition for all shells *except* PowerShell.
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+k",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalShellType != 'pwsh'",
    // Clear the screen and the scrollback buffer.
    // For shells other than PowerShell that is sufficient.
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear"
},

// Override for PowerShell, to compensate for the following bugs:
// * https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/841
// * https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19479
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+k",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalShellType == 'pwsh'",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            // Clear the screen and the scrollback buffer.
            "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
            // Additionally send Ctrl-L to PowerShell to clear only the current 
            // screen, which makes PowerShell aware of the new cursor position.
            {
                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                "args": {
                    "text": "\u000c" // Ctrl-L (FF)            
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Alternative workaround that *does* work with `ctrl+k`** even in v1.77.3 (and probably earlier):

Namely if you **send a command that emits VT / ANSI escape sequences to a PowerShell terminal that provides equivalent functionality**, but note that you may briefly see that command getting "typed" (in an automated fashion when the text is sent by Visual Studio Code), which **can be visually disruptive**:

```json
// General definition for all shells *except* PowerShell.
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalShellType != 'pwsh'",
    // Clear the screen and the scrollback buffer.
    // For shells other than PowerShell that is sufficient.
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear"
},

// Override for PowerShell, to compensate for the following bugs:
// * https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/841
// * https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19479
{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "when": "terminalFocus && terminalShellType == 'pwsh'",
    // Send a VT / ANSI escape sequence that clears the screen and
    // and the scrollback buffers and resets the cursor position.
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
        "text": "[Console]::Write(\"$([char] 0x1b)[2J$([char] 0x1b)[3J$([char] 0x1b)[H\")\u000d"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've decided to do "Ctrl+L" before doing "Ctrl+K" and that works well. Only simple workaround I've found. So essentially I am clearing the terminal before.

Comment: @leun, "Ctrl+L" is a good find, and as it turns out you can _incorporate_ it into a single keyboard-shortcut definition, since VSCode now supports running _multiple_ commands. Alas, due to a bug, "Ctrl+K" cannot currently be used with multiple commands, but there's a (somewhat suboptimal) workaround - please see my update.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However it seems to still be an issue when I added your code which overrides for PowerShell.

Comment: @leun, the first solution requires at least VSCode v1.77. The second solution probably works in earlier versions too. Does neither work for you? Both do for me. Note that, in either solution, the two definitions must be placed inside `keybindings.json` _in the order shown_, because later definitions take precedence over earlier ones.

Comment: @leun, also see my update re only needing _one_ definition per workaround if you don't expect to run `cmd.exe` sessions in the integrated terminal (if you do, `^L` will print to the screen after having cleared it).

Comment: @leun, on second thought I've removed the ordering requirement of the two definitions by replacing the `"when":` property of the first definition with `"terminalFocus && terminalShellType != 'pwsh'"`

Comment: If I understood correctly, regarding the second solution, I should only add the code below `// Override for PowerShell, to compensate for the following bugs:` as I am using PowerShell. Im using VS Code Version: 1.77.1.

Comment: @leun, if you want to use `ctrl+k` (rather than `ctrl+shift+k` or another shortcut), you must use the 2nd solution. If you need `ctrl+k` to work _only_ in PowerShell, then, yes, the definition after `// Override for PowerShell, to compensate for the following bugs:` is sufficient. Otherwise, use both.

Comment: This is what I get if use the second solution. As I am not familiar with the syntax in this file, I dont know what it is complaining on.

https://gyazo.com/2eca5ddff3791aa195343cb5ad8077c1

Comment: @leun: `keybindings.json` is a JSON file that must have a top-level array. That is, you must place the definitions inside `[` and `]` (the answer now mentions that too). That is, the overall structure must be `[ { ... }, { ... } ]`

Comment: thank you, I placed the code in between the square brackets but it seems to complain at this  `"command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",` Something along the lines of a trailing comma, so I removed it and got no errors. However the problem still presists.

Comment: Idk but it seems like I am missing something, if copying and pasting this code in between the square brackets works for you...

Comment: @leun: Try the content from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/d3d76e70b3494818a35865e22826b276), which works as-is for me. Note the caveat re potentially losing preexisting definitions and the instructions for how to avoid that.

Comment: @leun: Just saw the update to your previous comment: yes, there was an extraneous `,`, which I've now removed. However, even without this correction everything should work, because Visual Studio Code tolerates such extra `,` chars. (Another respect in which it is more lenient than the JSON standard is that allows `//` _comments_.)

Comment: This is pretty odd, I've added the code as shown in the image, killed the terminal and started a new one and the problem still persists.

https://gyazo.com/19daabf8f8acade64369defbdceefc00

Comment: @leun: Restart Visual Code and see if that helps.

Comment: Yea, same problem unfortunately...

Comment: @leun, unfortunately, I'm out of ideas. If the screen gets cleared but the cursor position is off, the implication is that the `terminalShellType == 'pwsh'` part of the `when` clause isn't working they way it does for me. (VSCode v1.77.3, en-US culture, with PowerShell extension v2023.3.3). If you keep only the second object and remove `terminalShellType == 'pwsh', you may get it to work, but then it would work for PowerShell _only_. As a last resort, you could use a _different_ shortcut, just for PowerShell (in which case the first workaround again becomes an option).

Comment: Yea, I think Im gonna try a few more things. Thank you